# external map.jar for the project

Tags: android, android-mapview

I want to use mapview in my android project without selecting Google APIs as my API. Therefore I have added map.jar file as an external library. But when I'm running the project it crashes saying java.lang.noclassdeffounderror. Is there any need to register any imported jar files in manifest??please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

1) Put the following line in the **application** (important) element of AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

2) extend MapActivity instead of Activity.

enjoy!